# What are ways that you might analyze relations extracted from text

Tags: natural-language-processing

In the coursera NLP course, Dan Jurofsky says you might want to extract relations from text to serve as input to other algorithms. What are examples of ways that researchers have used or might use relations extracted from text as the input for later "downstream" algorithms?

Comment: one common one is trigrams.... even used in google translate afaik... etc... but virtually anything extracted whatsoever is a "relation"....